# Проблема с отладчиком

Tags: visual-studio, отладка

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема. У меня не получается использовать отладчик графики в VS2022. Постоянно эта ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

VS запущена в режиме администратора. Также при отладке шейдеров такая ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *"VS запущена в режиме администратора."* - этого делать не надо. Следует убедиться, что устройство создается со дебаг флагом и что шейдеры компилируются с отладочной информацией. см https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50591937/how-do-i-launch-the-hlsl-debugger-in-visual-studio-2017/50592268#50592268

Comment: @user7860670 на другом пк работает